# Create macro with several options

Tags: macros, etoolbox, optional-arguments

I struggle to create a macro that can take several options. What I want to create is for `\mycommand[up,middle]{Macro}` to output `Macro with 'up' and 'middle' specified`. Using `etoolbox` in the MWE below I can output single options as well as when nothing or an invalid option is given. But I don't know how to output multiple options.

I do not have to use `etoolbox`, but I quite like the syntax. David Carlisle suggested something like `\newcommand\foo[2][]{\@for\tmp:=#1\do{.... something with \tmp and #2...}}` but I don't see how I can apply this to my example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd{\mycommand}[2][]{%
 \ifstrequal{#1}{up}{% option up
   #2 with `up' specified
   }{% option middle
   \ifstrequal{#1}{middle}{%
    #2 with `middle' specified
    }{% nothing specified
    \ifstrempty{#1}{%
     #2 with nothing specified
     }{% something specified
     #2 is invalid
   }{\relax}%
  }{\relax}%
 }%
}%

\begin{document}

\mycommand[up]{Macro}

\mycommand[middle]{Macro}

\mycommand[]{Macro}

\mycommand[bla]{Macro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It depends on what `up` and `middle` should do: are they independent?

Comment: I seem to recall that the `xargs` package can do something like this, as would more powerful packages that implement a key-value syntax.

Comment: Yes, they are placeholders to execute independent commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The suggestion to use `\@for` might work out something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mycommand}[2][]{% first the options that are equal for all
  \@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\tmp}{up}
      {'up' seen}%
      {%
        \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\tmp}{middle}
          {'middle' seen}
          {%
            \expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\tmp}
              {}
              {INVALID}%
          }%
      }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mycommand[up]{Macro}

\mycommand[middle]{Macro}

\mycommand[]{Macro}

\mycommand[bla]{Macro}


\end{document}
```

As I don't know what 'payload' you want, I've just typeset information on what has been seen: in a real case, this would probably be used to set up a switch or macro for use after the `\do` argument is complete.

Comment: Yes, that does exactly what I asked for. But I just realised that my objective is a bit more complex and I probably have to use keyvalues.

Comment: @Jörg I was not sure, but tried to stick to what was asked :-)

Comment: Yes, it does so perfectly :). But after thinking about my problem a bit more I think keyvalues work better for what I need. I basically have four options and they are in pairs, so `Options A/B` and `Options X/Y`. So I want to allow for A/X, A/Y, B/X, B/Y simultaneously, but not for A/B and X/Y simultaneously. I think in this case creating keyvalues with `Option1=A/B`, `Option2=X/Y` is a better strategy.

Comment: @Jörg it might be better to ask a new question; follow-up questions are perfectly acceptable on the site :)

Comment: @cmhughes I know :). My comment was meant as a statement, not a question.

Answer (score 4):

You could give one of the keyval packages a try, eg `xkeyval`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@choicekey+{myKeys}{foo}[\val\nr]{up,middle}{%
  \ifcase\nr\relax
      \def\keyval{up}       \or
      \def\keyval{middle}   
  \fi}{\def\keyval{\{not defined\}}} 
\makeatother

\newcommand\mycommand[2][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\def\keyval{\{empty\}} 
  \else\setkeys{myKeys}{#1}\fi
  we do something which depends to \keyval
}%

\begin{document}

\mycommand[foo=up]{Macro}

\mycommand[foo=middle]{Macro}

\mycommand[]{Macro}

\mycommand[foo=bla]{Macro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In general, `\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\setkeys{myKeys}{#1}\fi` (i.e., not setting keys because the current key-value list is empty) isn't advisable. There may be preset/postset keys, which won't be set with this type of call. *xkeyval* will not process an empty key-value list, but might call preset/postset keys for the current prefix and family.

Comment: I know all that! And it has nothing to do with the question to test if the argument is empty or not on macro level and not on `xkeyval` level.

Comment: A question of opinion! I don't know the difference between the 'levels' you refer to.

Comment: This comment confuses me. @ErrMist could you elaborate a bit on why you think this is an issue?

Comment: See comment at the foot of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyreader}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\krddefinekeys[JKV]{jorg}[jorg@]{%
  choice/key1/a+x/{
      a+x.do=\def\currcolor{blue},
      a+y.do=\def\currcolor{green},
      b+x.do=\def\currcolor{red},
      b+y.do=\def\currcolor{magenta}
    }
    /\def\val{Value of key1: #1}
  ;
  choice/align/justified/{
      center.do=\def\curralign{center},
      right.do=\def\curralign{flushright},
      left.do=\def\curralign{flushleft},
      justified.do=\def\curralign{@justified},
    }
  ;
}
\krdpresetkeys[JKV]{jorg}{key1=a+x,align=justified}
\def\@justified{}
\def\end@justified{}

% Tests:
\newcommand\jorgcommand[2][]{%
  \krdsetkeys[JKV]{jorg}{#1}%
  \endgraf\bigskip\noindent\textbf{\val}\endgraf
  \begin{\curralign}%
  \removelastskip
  \textcolor{\currcolor}{#2}%
  \end{\curralign}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\atext{%
  \texttt{choice} keys of pre-version~0.5 of \texttt{keyreader} package will always check 
  their values against the state pattern and raise an error if 
  there is no match. So you don't have to specify a fallback error message.
}

\jorgcommand[key1=a+x,align=justified]{\atext}
\jorgcommand[key1=a+y,align=center]{\atext}
\jorgcommand[key1=b+x,align=right]{\atext}
\jorgcommand[key1=b+y,align=left]{\atext}
\jorgcommand{\atext}
% Invalid value for key1 ('x+y' not allowed):
% \jorgcommand[key1=x+y]{\atext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Note to answer a question by the OP about preset keys

In my example above you find the call `\jorgcommand{\atext}`. This calls no optional argument, so argument `#1` is empty in `\jorgcommand`. Hence, in this case `\jorgcommand` uses the values of the keys in the instant

```
\krdpresetkeys[JKV]{jorg}{key1=a+x,align=justified}
```

If we were to use

```
\newcommand\jorgcommand[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \krdsetkeys[JKV]{jorg}{#1}%
  \fi
  ...#2...
}
```

as Herbert suggested, the preset key-values will not be called. We would, therefore, have inadvertently applied the latest values of the keys, which isn't the intended or right step. Preset keys are set only when `\setkeys` or `\krdsetkeys` is instantiated.